# Complex path is not cut

Tags: three.js

I need to cut out the complex profile. The circle is cut, and California is not cut. Here's an example. This does not work:

```
squareShape.holes.push( californiaPath );
```

And it - works:

```
var Radius = 190, x0 = 1440, y0 = 1260;
var CirclePath = new THREE.Path();
CirclePath.moveTo( x0 + Radius, y0 );
CirclePath.absarc( x0, y0, Radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true );
CirclePath.closePath();
squareShape.holes.push( CirclePath );
```

look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/alexan0308/vyx10vah/). What happens?

Comment: California is not cut?

Comment: >California is not cut? - Yes!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vyx10vah/1/ Use the current version of three.js and make sure your winding order is counter-clockwise when you create a `Shape`. You will have to study the code to understand why this is important.

Comment: how many amazing mysteries in the universe! thank you =)

Comment: See if you can figure out when winding order is important for paths/shapes/holes and post your answer.

Comment: it's too hard for me :)